# Подсчет чисел с заданными условиями

Tags: delphi

Как реализовать программу, которая выводит все четырехзначные числа abcd, для которых выполняются следующие условия:

- `a,b,c,d` - разные цифры;
- `a*b = c*d`

Comment: Опиши какие условия сделла ты для решения вопроса?

Comment: @tkoff Учебный вопрос подразумевает самостоятельную попытку решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм.

1. Пусть i равно нулю.
2. Сформировать четырехзначное число из i.
3. Проверить условие вывода числа
4. Если условие верно, вывести число.
5. Увеличить i.
6. Если i меньше 10000, перейти на шаг 2.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе перебор 10000 чисел на современной технике очень быстр, но преподавателю явно нужно что-то иное. Вот пример тупого перебора по каждой цифре.

```
program fn;
type digit = 0 .. 9;
var i1, i2, i3, i4 : digit;
    s2, s3, s4: set of digit;

begin
    for i1 := 0 to 9 do begin
        s2 := [0..9] - [i1];
        for i2 := 0 to 9 do begin
            (* сумма пары цифр не может быть <3 (1+2,0+3) и >15(7+8,9+6) *)
            if not (i2 in s2) or (i1+i2 < 3) or (i1+i2 > 15) then continue;
            s3 := s2 - [i2];
            for i3 := 0 to 9 do begin
                if (not i3 in s3) or (i3 > i1 + i2) then continue;
                s4 := s3 - [i3];
                for i4 := 0 to 9 do
                    if (i4 in s4) and (i1+i2 = i3+i4) then 
                        writeln(i1:1, i2:1, i3:1, i4:1);
            end
        end
    end
end.
```